# How can I insert searchable data into one column, have it display linked editable data in the next?

Tags: spreadsheet

I want to be able to put a students name or I.D., have google sheets search through spreadsheets for that student, then populate information in the next column (their phone number and current grade). The kicker is that I want to edit the populated grade and have it linked to the original sheet so it gets updated.

I have the current sheet called "UpdateInfo". All the other sheets are categorized by student name. In each students sheet, their names are in "A1", their phone numbers are in "B1" and their grades are in "C1". All student sheets follow the same format. I had a friend explain how VLOOKUP can find and populate the info. We have no clue how to link it and have it update once edited.

I want to open "UpdateInfo", insert names of all the students, have their numbers and grades populate in the next columns, then finally edit the information and have it also updated in the students' original sheet.

Comment: Can you share screenshot of your excel? It is hard to understand problem when you just write test. Also, share what you have tried till now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want, maybe you can take a look at the sheet as attched above.
The "data" sheet for you to store your students information,
the "check" sheet for you to find out the answers by select the student's name.
You can add as much as students you want at the "data" sheet,
it will all appear as an options in the "check" sheet.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x8s36Ph20sjozOjuekJgH3-UMDz_kBicequaHrI8k8E/edit?usp=sharing

This is the link of the spreadsheets, which is supposed attached in the previous post...